# Using same css class with different values

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to use the [DataTable](https://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/story/datatable--default) component of carbon-react, I have 2 instances of of DataTables: one is inside a Modal and one in other component, and I need to control 2 different sizes/behavior of them.

So I tried achieving it by css:

```
#wide-table.bx--data-table-container {
    max-width: 1300px !important;
    max-height: 600px !important;

    width: 100% !important;
    height: 50% !important;
}

#narrow-table.bx--data-table-container {
    max-width: 850px !important;
    max-height: 400px !important;

    width: 100% !important;
    height: 50% !important;
}
```

and then to use the Id:

```
<DataTable id="wide-table"
```

But it's not taking affect!

Comment: For sure I used the dev. tools to inspect it, read my post carefully... the class that I'm overriding is the same class that you are talking about "bx--data-table-container"!!!! But I need two versions of it, that's my problem.

Comment: Yes - my apologies, I misread the class name.